# How can I "diff" all attributes and properties of two DOM elements?

Tags: google-chrome, dom, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, blink

Chrome/Opera users in Windows: wrap the following lines in any valid html skeleton:

```
<a id = "a" href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
<br />
Some text THEN a link <a id="b" href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
<br />
<a id="c" href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> A link THEN some text
<br />
```

Now, putting the mouse aside and using only <kbd>tab</kbd> and the the context key/menu key/application key*, attempt to "save link as". The first and third fail and attempt to save the current page.
The second works as it should. Additionally, if I use a css reset library like normalizr, it fails on all of the links.

In IE and Firefox, all links behave as they should. This only happens in blink-based browsers.

*(call it what you will, it's the image of a mouse pointer pointing at a context menu, usually bottom right of a keyboard's alpha section and is relied on by keyboard users and blind/screenreader users).

Chromium have removed the "bug" tag on [my ticket](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362147) and say the desire for consistent behaviour, not just between mouse and keyboard, but even between placement of links on a line, is a "feature request".

As well as assembling a small army of blind users to explain why excluding them sucks, I'm hoping to put together rock solid technical proof too.

The trouble is, after almost the entire morning, I can't find a way of "diff"-ing the two DOM elements to find out what causes one to work and one to fail.

There are many stackoverflow answers that point to something like:

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
alert( a.isEqualNode(b) );
```

But it doesn't help me much anyway. The trouble is, drilling down through all the event properties, listeners, elements, styles etc seems to be an endless task - on the "blur" listener alone there appear to be almost infinite levels of property. As you can tell, I'm a but out of my depth at this point.

### tl;dr version of my question

Is there any way of taking **everything** the DOM/browser knows about an element, and comparing it with what should be an identical element?

### Clarification

This is a question relating to **accessibility** for users relying on **keyboard-shortcuts** solely affecting browsers built round the **blink** rendering engine. This relates to DOM, not javascript. Please consider the question carefully before removing those three essential tags or adding other irrelevant ones. Thank you.

Comment: The part about "Save link as..." is not really relevant here. That is a bug though, but I would hardly call it a show stopper for accessibility. I don't recall when I saved a page without visiting it first. Therefore I made some edits to the tags. You need to make a function like mentioned on this [Code Review SO Question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/javascript-function-to-get-dom-elements-by-any-attribute)

Comment: Hi @RyanB; thanks for the grammatical improvements and link to the CR script. However, the "save link as" is ENTIRELY relevant here - the example was to demonstrate the problem, not to give a full use-case scenario for one user's particular browsing habits. Given that this makes saving files impossible (ie: a showstopper) IN SOME CIRCUMSTANCES for users who rely on the "keyboard shortcuts", who are usually also "accessibility" technology users, and ONLY affects "blink"-based browsers, can I ask for more detail on why you removed each of those three quoted tags?

Comment: To add to the above, the tags you removed and their descriptions:

blink: "Blink is an open source rendering engine forked from WebKit. It is included in Google Chrome 28+ and Opera 14+. Blink includes a different multiprocess architecture than WebKit2, and the V8 JavaScript engine, rather than JavaScriptCore."
- My issue is only with these browsers.

accessibility: "Accessibility: the practice of making software which functions smoothly for users with a variety of disabilities, including blindness, deafness, and paralysis among others."
 - Issue only occurs when users rely on keyboard nav.